# Bash - Print first available (not in the array) number divisible by 8

Tags: bash

I have an array in Bash that will print out a series of numbers. I would like to find the first available (read: not in the array) number divisible by 8 (including 0).

```
for i in "${NUMS[@]}"
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Will output:

```
0
1
2
3
8
9
10
11
```

So in this example, the value would be "16". If 0 or 8 were missing from that array, those would have been selected.

I'm looking at something like:

```
echo "${NUMS[@]}" | awk -v RS='\\s+' '{ a[$1] } END { for(i = 0; i in a; ++i); print i }'
```

which will give me the first missing integer (4), but have not yet gotten a working result for a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
printf '%s\n' "${NUMS[@]}" |
    sort -n |
    awk 'BEGIN { num=0 } $0 == num { num+=8 } END { print num }'
```

The idea is to start looking for the number 0, if you find it you start looking for 8 and so on. The variable `num` gets incremented by 8 each time the number is found to give the next multiple of 8 that hasn't been seen yet.

Sort is only needed if the array isn't already ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I had working prior to reading Graeme's (much better) solution:

```
POSSIBLE_VALUES=($(seq 0 8 255))

for i in ${POSSIBLE_VALUES[@]}
do
match=0
  for j in ${NUMS[@]}
  do
    if [ "${i}" == "${j}" ]
    then
      match=1
      break
    fi
  done
if [ "${match}" == 0 ]
then
  c+=($i)
fi
done

echo ${c[0]}
```